# Entity Framework Core 2.1 SQLite provider nuget package installs missing references

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, nuget, entity-framework-core

I have a asp.net web api application (full .net, not core) that has a simple datastore that is currently using a SQL compact edition, which I access via EF 6.1.

I want to swap to SQLite, and at the same time I thought I might go over to EFCore.

I thought I would have a look in a sample app. When I source for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` I actually find 2 packages `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core`, but I think they are the same (as I installed one and now the other is also highlighted as installed in nuget package manager.

My real question here is about some missing references...
My test app is just a WPF targeting .net 4.7, and I get the following missing references...

[image]

The app, however, still seems to build. I have not tried actually using it yet.

Has anyone else had these missing references, and if so, do we just remove them?

Thanks in advance for any info

**[EDIT1]**
Here are the package.config contents as asked in the comments

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
      <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Remotion.Linq" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" version="1.1.7" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.core" version="1.1.7" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.linux" version="1.1.7" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.osx" version="1.1.7" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.v110_xp" version="1.1.7" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.net45" version="1.1.7" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Collections" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.4.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.4.1" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Interactive.Async" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Linq" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.0.12" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="System.Threading" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net47" />
    </packages>
```

Comment: what does the package.config show for the TargetFramework for each item in the that file?  Just ran your scenario and it appears to build without errors and has no bangouts on the dependencies.  Scratch created WPF test app with 4.7.   I suspect there are artifacts for EF 6.1 still present.

Comment: @mvermef - added the contents of package.config to the question. Yes mine build fine too, I just get the warning about the missing references.

Comment: hmm nothing out of order... Have you tried to close down VS and or rebooted see if something might be interfering?

Comment: @mvermef - Yes just restarted VS, and also then rebooted whole machine, just to make sure - still got the missing refs. Perhaps something out of date with the nuget package (wonder if I should report it, but thought would look for any other opinions before doing so)

Comment: how far into that "test project" are you?

Comment: @mvermef Not much, added: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`. generated POCOs from an existing  SQLite database using `Scaffold-DbContext`, done an insert and read. All seems to work even though I have the missing references.